# Como realizar mais de um select para apenas dois campos de outra tabela

Tags: sql, sql-select

Não estou conseguindo selecionar mais de uma tabela para exibir somente os dados de ID e nome (tabela t_cadclientes), estou realizando o SELECT da tabela t_cadcontratos inteira com WHERE no número de contrato passado via SELECT de outra página:
campos em comum das tabelas = "Ficha";

```
include"../Connections/config.php";
    $conexao = mysql_connect("$hostname_config","$username_config","$password_config")
                or die ("Erro ao realizar a conexão com o banco de dados, por favor informe o administrador do sistema (suporte@emperiumcode.com) ou envie um email para contato@buchmannoptical.com.br !");
    $db = mysql_select_db("$database_config")
                or die ("Erro ao selecionar o banco de dados, por favor informe o administrador do sistema (suporte@emperiumcode.com) ou envie um email para contato@buchmannoptical.com.br !");
    $contrato = $_GET['id'];
    $seleciona = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_cadcontratos WHERE NumContrato = '$contrato'");

    if($seleciona == '') {
        echo "Erro ao Selecionar, tente novamente !";
    } else {  
        while($res_id = mysql_fetch_array($seleciona)){
        $pdf->Cell(15,0.5,"N Contrato:",0,0,'R'); $pdf->Cell(2,0.5,$res_id['NumContrato'],1,1,'C');
....
```

Estrutura tabela t_cadclientes

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t_cadclientes` (
  `Ficha` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Snome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Endereco` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DataNascimento` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bairro` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cidade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Uf` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cpf` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cgc` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Identidade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Carteira Trabalho` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pai` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mae` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EstadoCivil` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cep` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NomeEmpresa` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndEmpresa` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BairroEmpresa` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CidadeEmpresa` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FoneEmpresa` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ramal` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Renda` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NomeConjuge` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmpresaConjuge` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndEmpresaConjuge` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BairroEmpresaConjuge` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CidadeEmpresaConjuge` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FoneEmpresaConjuge` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RamalEmpresaConjuge` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RendaConjuge` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NomeContato` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndContato` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FoneContato` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Relacao` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Loja1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Loja2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AtualizacaoCadastr` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `FichaDesde` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ficha`),
  KEY `Identidade` (`Identidade`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=23464 ;
```

estrutura tabela t_cadcontratos

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t_cadcontratos` (
  `Ficha` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `NumContrato` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DataContrato` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `QuantParcelas` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '3',
  `ValorContrato` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `Entrada` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `Saldo` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `DescricaoProduto` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QuantProdutos` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Vendedor` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FormaPagamento` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'CREDIÁRIO',
  PRIMARY KEY (`NumContrato`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2160 ;
```

Comment: Poderia postar a estrutura básica das tabelas? O que você realmente quer é como trazer no mesmo select dados de ambas as tabelas usando JOIN?

Comment: @Caputo acabei de postar a estrutura, no aguardo!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fica assim a consulta das duas tabelas:

```
SELECT 
   contr.*, -- Todas as colunas da tabela t_cadcontratos
   client.Snome -- Coluna nome da tabela t_cadclientes 
FROM t_cadcontratos contr 
   INNER JOIN t_cadclientes client ON contr.Ficha = client.Ficha
WHERE NumContrato = '$contrato'
```

Links para estudo;

> [Syntax Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)
>   [Relacionamento de Tabelas](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql/)

Comment: Obrigado @KaduAmaral pelo apoio, funcionou! vou estudar mais sobre join e enfins, abraço.

Comment: Bons estudos @RafaelAssmann ;)

Answer (score 2):

Para trazer somente os campos que pediu, ficaria

```
SELECT 
   CLI.Ficha,
   CLI.Snome
FROM t_cadcontratos CON 
   INNER JOIN t_cadclientes CLI ON CON.Ficha = CLI.Ficha
WHERE CON.NumContrato = '$contrato'
```